# Integral curves and Picard-Lindelöf theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The picture one in below is from the Jost's Riemannian geometry and geometric analysis .

$X$ is smooth tangent vector field. So , $X(c_p(t))$ is local Lipschitz. So, there is unique solution by Picard–Lindelöf theorem, but how to know the solution is smooth ?

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: I assume that by "smooth" you understand "$C^{1}$ w.r.t to $t$". Then it seems to be following straight from Picar-Lindelöf theorem and from the properties of rhs: you know that time derivative of solution exists and it's at least a differentiable function of $t$, hence when you plug it into rhs you get something that varies continuously w.r.t to $t$. And that's why $y'(t)$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $c' = X \circ c$ and both $X,c$ are differentiable, the chain rule tells us $c'$ is differentiable with $c''= DX \circ c'.$ But now we know $c$ is twice differentiable, so (assuming $X$ is too) we can differentiate again to see that $c$ is thrice differentiable. If $X$ is smooth you can repeat this as many times as you like, so $c$ is smooth.